# Cannot open SQL files in VS2010 on Win7 x64

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2010, sql

If I try to open SQL files in  Visual Studio 2010 on Win7 x64, VS just hangs and I have to kille the process. This is happening with both local files and files on TFS.

I have no problem with opening SQL files in VS2012 on the same PC. What could be causing the problem?

UPD: Tested to open both local SQL files and files on TFS, VS hanging in both cases.

Here is the version information for VS2010.
[image]

Comment: Could it be the size of the files?

Comment: Was this previously working and is now not working or have you never been able to open SQL files in VS2010?

Comment: @Richard It was working in WinXP. Since I've got Win7, it stopped working.

Comment: @m4573r I doubt it. It happens with files of different sizes. As I said, the same files are opened in VS2012 with no problem.

Comment: I think you need to provide more information for people to be able to help?

Comment: @Richard what kind of information? I provided as much as I could.

Comment: Does VS2010 hand forever or does it eventually start responding? What does the screen look like when it's hanging (most likely the "not responding" white screen)? What plugins have you installed into VS2010? Have you tried uninstalling and re-installing VS2010?

Comment: @Richard ah sorry! Yeah, it starts to respond again after some time but if I open the tab with the SQL file, it hangs again. So I have to close that tab. I have NuGet and SlowCheetah extensions installed, and Resharper 7.1. No, I haven't tried to reinstall VS. I will try once I have time.

Comment: Maybe you could install PerfWatson and poke around in the reports it sends to MS? http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fa85b17d-3df2-49b1-bee6-71527ffef441